# (How) can I specify a specific configuration file name for my nhibernate configuration?

Tags: nhibernate, configuration

I'm using an NHibernateProvider library I found online, and I want to keep security and profile information separate from a collection of application databases I'm using; I intend to centralize the application services, but most applications will have their own database.

Googling nhibernate with multiple databases generates a long list of shockingly complicated processes.  I thought it would be simpler if I hardcoded a reference to nhibernateprovider.config and reference only that in the provider library to avoid any issues with potential conflicts with core applications also using nhibernate.  It seemed like a really simple idea, and I like simple... however, I cannot figure out any place to specify a configuration file when instantiating my session factory.  Googling generates too many unrelated hits.

1. Is it possible to explicitly specify a configuration file when instantiating a session factory, and if so,
2. How do you do it?
3. If it isn't possible, why the heck not?  This seems to be an obvious thing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
string configfile = "myNhibernate.config";
var config = new Configuration().Configure(configfile);
```

you can also share common information in the configfile and set the connectionstring dynamically befor constructing the sessionfactory

```
config.Properties[NHibernate.Cfg.Environment.ConnectionString] = connectionstring;
```

Comment: That does indeed seem to do the trick.  Knew there had to be a way.